# function as function parameter does not work

Tags: python-3.x, python-turtle

```
import turtle
t = turtle.Turtle()
def vary(shape,dup):
    while not out_of_bound():
        shape
        dup

def out_of_bound():#returns True if turtle is out of screen
    out = False
    height = (turtle.window_height()-30)/2
    width = (turtle.window_width()-30)/2
    if abs(t.xcor())>width or abs(t.ycor())>height:
        out = True
    return out

def linear(direction,distance):#for linear duplication
    try:
        origin_head = t.heading()
        t.seth(direction)
        t.up()
        t.fd(distance)
        t.seth(origin_head)#ensures duplication remains linear
    except:
        print('Invalid input.')

def circle(radius,steps=None,orient=None,circle_color=None,shape_color=None):#circle or shape in circle, orientation in degrees
    try:
        t.down()
        t.circle(-radius)
        t.up()
        t.circle(-radius,orient)#set orientation of the shape in circle
        t.down()
        t.circle(-radius,steps=steps)#draw shape in the circle
        t.up()
        t.lt(180)
        t.circle(radius,orient)#return to default position
        t.seth(0)
    except:
        print('Invalid input.')`enter code here`
```

above code is my attempt to use the turtle library to create patterns, in this case, in a linear manner. when I call the function, vary(circle(50,4,45),linear(0,100)) the while loop only draws one shape and stops, while the code continues to run. please help.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `vary` like that will not pass `circle` and `linear` as parameters to `vary`. What `vary` will receive in this case are the return values of those functions (in this case `None` for both). If you want to pass a function as a parameter, do not add the parentheses - they result in calling the function, which returns its return value.

Because of the above, the following code:

```py
    while not out_of_bound():
        shape
        dup
```

Is equivalent to this:

```py
    while not out_of_bound():
        None
        None
```

which obviously does nothing.

The following code should achieve your goal:

```py
def vary(shape, shape_args, dup, dup_args):
    while not out_of_bound():
        shape(*shape_args)
        dup(*dup_args)
```

Then call it like this: `vary(circle, (50,4,45), linear, (0,100))`.